# VB.NET and polymorphism

Tags: vb.net, casting, polymorphism

Is there a way to make VB.NET functions polymorph, when it comes to lists? The following code gives me a "invalid cast" error:

```
Sub TestBase()
    Dim a#()
    a = VEC.New_(42, 51, 2, 3, 4, 5) 'never mind, this just creates a non-empty list
    'at this point, a is a double()
    ARR.append(a, 5)
End Sub
Public Sub append(ByRef v, Val)
    ReDim Preserve v(0 To UBound(v) + 1) 'this line casts v into a object()
    v(UBound(v)) = Val
End Sub
```

Is there a correct way of doing this, apart from the fastiduous way of making one function per type?

Comment: Generics? public sub append(of T)(byref v() as T, Val as T)

Comment: Yes this does the trick, thanks!

Comment: Using untyped code while using a modern language that allows you to use `Option Strict On` is so... 1990s

Comment: @Peter B : I come from VBA, that's why. ;-)

Comment: @Pierre -- My advice: ditch all the VB-only habits you have and embrace the pure .NET features.  In fact, learn C#.

Comment: @rory.ap : I have a lot of VBA code which is fairly clean. I accumulated it for years. Going to C# would waste me a lot of time. But indeed I am now upgrading my code, which is very satisfying by itself. I see the things that I couldn't handle properly in VBA that are now getting much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rory.ap mentions, you should really be using lists.

That said, your issue can be solved by using generics like below:

```
public sub append(of T)(byref v() as T, Val as T)
        ReDim Preserve v(0 To UBound(v) + 1) 
        v(UBound(v)) = Val
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to learn to use those generics though: A < B does not work if both A abd B are type T...

Comment: @Pierre That's because, due to using generics, the compiler does not know how to compare the items, or even if then can be compared. You might use "public sub append(of T as IComparable)" to indicate a comparison must exist.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I would use another type of collection, like `List(Of T)` rather than an array since they're much easier to work with.

Then you can just do this:

```
Dim a As New List(Of Double)
a.Add(5)
```